# Basics of high voltage DC motor driver with IGBT

Tags: power-electronics, dc-motor, rectifier, motor-controller, igbt

I'm trying to drive 140V 4.5kW brushed DC pancake motor. I have to change motor speed and direction. All drive actions must be very smooth and sensitive.

I drew a simple 4 quadrant IGBT controlled driver schematic but I don't have enough experience with motor drivers and I need some advice for best way to drive this motor.

[image]

At the enterence, I will rectify AC voltage that comes from secondary side of transformer (not shown in schematic.  The primary side of the transformer is 3 phase 440VAC.

What is the proper AC voltage and phase number for this circuit?

My plan A is getting 1-phase 115VAC from secondary side and rectify it to ~160V DC. Is that proper?

I'm planning to use ~600V 30A IGBTs. Is that adequate?

I'm planning to get current value by Hall effect current sensor (ACS758) and motor speed from an absolute encoder. I will use STM32F7 mcu for closed loop calculations and generating PWM signals.

Is there any trick point? Is that the proper way?

I didn't use an inductor before motor.

Is it neccessary for any regulations?

I need expert advice about this driving DC motor issue.

Comment: 4500/140=32A, so you are way off. The switching elements do need higher current rating, due to switching losses.

Comment: So 60A or more will be enough

Comment: Without any calculation, it's hard te tell which IGBT is suitable.

Comment: What about calculations? Can't we say 60A or 100A is  enough ?

Comment: For 100Hz it would enough, I guess. By the way, for your app. would be more suitable a three phase transformer supply with 6-pulse SCR  = four quadrant + regeneration.

Comment: What is the main reason of this ? why 6-pulse SCR more suitable for this app ?